# openmp loop is very fast in the beginning, but becomes slow (almost stuck) afterwards

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a piece of code which I have palatalized, please see below. The code runs very fast in the beginning, however it slows down after specific iterations.

```
// something before this ...
// filename_list is quite long, 100k+ files

vector<string> some_string_list(filename_list.size(), " ");
int file_count = filename_list.size();

int counter = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:counter) schedule(auto)  
for (int i = 0; i < file_count; i++)
{
  string loop_filename = filename_list[i];  
  counter++;

  // The filename is used to call a class member function and get some data, the file is used for reading
  // This is the heavy part of code
  some_string_list[i] = someclassinstance.getSomeString(loop_filename, param1, param2);
  int temp = counter;
  if(temp % 1000 == 0)
  {
    cout << "." << flush;
  }
}

cout << endl;
```

I have tried different scheduling and chunk sizes, but it does not help. I appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like some sort of memory issue where you eventually run out of RAM, probably inside the `getSomeString` method. Make sure to close the files after you have used them and to free all dynamically allocated memory if such is used.

Comment: I am monitoring ram using top, nothing that I can see there...

Comment: Maybe it is good to mention that I am accessing a std::map (but not inserting) in the getSomeString member function

Comment: The heavy part of your algo consists in reading into files right? So unless you have a parallel file system, parallelising the loop won't bring you any speed-up, and even possibly slow down the code by messing up disk accesses (especially if your IO are not properly optimised in the first place). So what OS, what file system, what IO hardware and how are IOs performed?

Comment: As it stands your question is very vague and answering is mainly guessing. Please try to come up with a [mcve] of your problem. You also should describe more clearly what is "very fast", "beginning", "slow" and "specific iterations".

Comment: @Gilles, I know that by design the IO part is rather small (the files themselves are small), and the computation later (accessing std::map, sorting, etc) is the heavy part.

Comment: @Zulan, By very fast and very slow I mean: In the first ~200k iterations, the cpu is at about 1000% percent (about 32 cores used) and suddenly it drops to ~5-20%, similar to single core case as I checked. As I am printing dots (cout << "." << flush;) I see the progress semi-realtime. My guess is that somehow the scheduling becomes congested, but I do not know why and how to solve it..

Comment: @Gilles, about IO and OS, I am running on ubuntu 14.04 64bits, 16 cores and 32GB of ram, IO is done using c++ fstream., file system is ext4.

Comment: My guess is that your first files are cached in memory, so everything just go fast at the beginning. Then you reach a point where you need to actually access the disk, and you go back to (at best) sequential speed

Comment: @Gilles, Thanks. Does this caching in the memory happen automatically? I do not do anything specific to make this happen.

Comment: It is done by default by the OS. Have a look at the "cached" column of what the command `free` gives you. To make sure that caching is the issue, try to first flush the cache (as root, `sync && echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`) then retry your code to see if you still have the same behaviour.

Comment: It seems that you are right :) I cleared the cache. Now if I run the program, it will be slow from the beginning. If I press ctrl-c and rerun, then it is fast for the ones which were processed once, and slow again afterwards. So thanks a lot for helping me on this! Do you know a way to make things better here? somehow to cache files in advance? Or something to be changed (e.g. some other tools instead of openmp)?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the helpful comments.
Indeed the bottleneck is the IO (read) on HDD. 
The initial speed up was also a result of files being cached.
I copied the data on a SSD drive, and in this case, parallelization makes a huge and clear difference, and IO does not become a big bottleneck.